# Org tables: Wrap all fields in column to a given size

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In org it is possible to set a column width like follows:

```
|---+------------------------------|               |---+----------------| 
|   |                              |               |   | <14>           | 
| 1 | one                          |               | 1 | one            | 
| 2 | two                          |     ----\     | 2 | two            | 
| 3 | This is a long chunk of text |     ----/     | 3 | This is a lo=> | 
| 4 | four                         |               | 4 | four           | 
|---+------------------------------|               |---+----------------|
```

I would like to obtain this layout instead:

```
|---+----------------|
|   | <14>           |
| 1 | one            |
| 2 | two            |
| 3 | This is a long |
|   | chunk of text  |
| 4 | four           |
|---+----------------|
```

Of course I can use `M-S-<down>`  and `M-<ret>` to insert a new row and wrap the long field.
However, for many fields, this is inconvenient. Is there any hack or package to speed up this process?

Comment: AFAIK It's not possible.  You could try to request it on the org mailing list.  I am not sure `org-table` would easily be amended, though.

Answer (score 11):

I am new to the Org API and I would be glad if you could give a look to the code and share some comments.

As for the proposed solution, consider the following table:

```
|---+--------------------------------+---|
| 1 | one                            | a |
| 2 | two                            | b |
| 3 | This is a long chunk of text   | c |
| 4 | four                           | d |
| 5 | Yet another long chunk of text | e |
|---+--------------------------------+---|
```

Put the cursor anywhere in the second column and type:

```
M-x org-table-wrap-to-width
```

Enter a column  width as requested. E.g., entering  `15`, you get:

```
|---+----------------+---|
| 1 | one            | a |
| 2 | two            | b |
| 3 | This is a long | c |
|   | chunk of text  |   |
| 4 | four           | d |
| 5 | Yet another    | e |
|   | long chunk of  |   |
|   | text           |   |
|---+----------------+---|
```

If you are dissatisfied with this width and want to try a different value, use the Emacs standard undo, which will restore the previous layout, so you can rerun the  wrap function.

Here's the code. If you know Org, please, give feedback.

```
(defun org-table-wrap-to-width (width)
  "Wrap current column to WIDTH."
  (interactive (list (read-number "Enter column width: ")))
  (org-table-check-inside-data-field)
  (org-table-align)

  (let (cline (ccol (org-table-current-column)) new-row-count (more t))
    (org-table-goto-line 1)
    (org-table-goto-column ccol)

    (while more
      (setq cline (org-table-current-line))

      ;; Cut current field
      (org-table-copy-region (point) (point) 'cut)

      ;; Justify for width
      (setq org-table-clip 
            (mapcar 'list (org-wrap (caar org-table-clip) width nil)))

      ;; Add new lines and fill
      (setq new-row-count (1- (length org-table-clip)))
      (if (> new-row-count 0)
          (org-table-insert-n-row-below new-row-count)) 
      (org-table-goto-line cline)
      (org-table-goto-column ccol)
      (org-table-paste-rectangle)
      (org-table-goto-line (+ cline new-row-count))

      ;; Move to next line
      (setq more (org-table-goto-line (+ cline new-row-count 1)))
      (org-table-goto-column ccol))

    (org-table-goto-line 1)
    (org-table-goto-column ccol)))

(defun org-table-insert-n-row-below (n)
  "Insert N new lines below the current."
  (let* ((line (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
         (new (org-table-clean-line line)))
    ;; Fix the first field if necessary
    (if (string-match "^[ \t]*| *[#$] *|" line)
        (setq new (replace-match (match-string 0 line) t t new)))
    (beginning-of-line 2)
    (setq new
      (apply 'concat (make-list n (concat new "\n"))))
    (let (org-table-may-need-update) (insert-before-markers new))  ;;; remove? 
    (beginning-of-line 0)
    (re-search-forward "| ?" (point-at-eol) t)
    (and (or org-table-may-need-update org-table-overlay-coordinates) ;;; remove? 
         (org-table-align))
    (org-table-fix-formulas "@" nil (1- (org-table-current-dline)) n)))
```

Comment: Interesting. I guess it should be noted though, that org-mode does not know the lines were wrapped, so, for example, sorting will most likely mess it all up. It still looks useful, e.g. to use before exporting.

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires: It would be relatively easy to add a symbol like `"` to mark the begin/end of a field spanning multiple lines, in order to go back to the non wrapped version, manipulate, and re-wrap. I am not sure whether this should be a visible symbol (which would make the layout less polished) or an invisible one (which would make the table structure obfuscated).

Comment: Yes, that could be interesting. Emacs, and others, use some visible "curly arrow" symbols to show that there is line wrapping (there is probably some unicode character for that but I found none in a quick search)

Comment: What about using the [broken bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Solid_vertical_bar_vs_broken_bar) in place of the vertical bar, `|`, to indicate when a row is wrapped?

Comment: @Melioratus Great choice. Maybe set as a variable `org-table-wrapped-boundary-char` or similar?  Also would be nice to have the bars in alternate row differ by color.