# Wrap cell content in an org mode table

Tags: org-table, table

I have a table like this:

```
| Verse No | Verse      |
|          | <10>       |
|        1 | line1 li=> |
|        2 | line2 li=> |
```

I would like to view it as

```
| Verse No | Verse      |
|          | <10>       |
|        1 | line1 line |
|          | 1 line1    |
|        2 | line2 line |
|          | 2 line2    |
```

I am aware of `` C-c ` `` but that's not enough, I want to see all text simultaneously. Read only is OK if need be.

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47236/8353) helps.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30837/3975)

Comment: After trying `tabel.el`, as well as two MacOS apps called TableFlip and MarkupTable, I decided the best solution for me is to simply edit the table in Excel or Google Sheets, then copy-paste the contents onto this site to convert to org-mode table format: https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

org-mode has 2 table formats, the default `org-table` and the other is `table.el`.

Cell wrapping is available for tables in `table.el` format.

**Try this**

1. Remove the extra row with `<10>` so your table will look similar to the example below:

   ```
   | Verse No | Verse             |
   |        1 | Line1 Line1 Line1 |
   |        2 | Line2 Line2 Line2 |
   ```

   > *Tip:* Add a blank line above and below the table. The blank lines should prevent a bug when converting the table with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd>. Thanks to @ComproPrasad for troubleshooting and providing the workaround.
2. Place your cursor, a.k.a the point, inside updated table then type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> and answer `y`. The updated table should look similar to example below:

   ```
   +----------+-------------------+
   | Verse No | Verse             |
   +----------+-------------------+
   |        1 | Line1 Line1 Line1 |
   +----------+-------------------+
   |        2 | Line2 Line2 Line2 |
   +----------+-------------------+
   ```
3. Place your cursor inside updated table then type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> and a new window or frame will appear.
4. Type <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>t-r-t</kbd> and each table cell should be highlighted.
5. Place your cursor inside second column and type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> until the column is the desired width.

   > **Tip:** Use the universal argument key binding <kbd>C-u</kbd> to quickly repeat this step. For example, If your cell is 500 characters and you want to adjust the width to 10 characters do <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>490</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> which will repeat <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> command 490 times.
6. Type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> to finish editing table. These steps should leave you with a similar to the example below:

   ```
   +----------+------+
   | Verse No | Verse|
   +----------+------+
   |        1 |Line1 |
   |          |Line1 |
   |          |Line1 |
   +----------+------+
   |        2 |Line2 |
   |          |Line2 |
   |          |Line2 |
   +----------+------+
   ```

Thanks for asking your question!
Hope that helped!

---

> **This answer tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   org version: Org mode version 9.1.2

Comment: Step 4 is not needed (at least in current emacs v. 26).

Pressing C-c ~ as the step 7 converts the table.el table back to editable org table.

Comment: @Heikki Great to know! Thanks!  On v.25 I needed to add step 4 because to table wasn’t being recognized but wasn’t throwing any errors either. Did you want me to add step 7 `C-c ~` to convert back to `org-table` format?

Comment: is there an option to speed up step 5, say when I have 500 char of content and I want them wrapped to 10 chars?

Comment: @user2740 - I asked myself the same question while writing my answer. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find a function to reset the column widths to a specific value. However, I did find a workaround using the universal argument key binding `C-u`. Try this `C-u 490 C-c C-c <` which should repeat step 5 four hundred and ninety times. Please reply if you find the workaround helpful and I’ll update my answer. Hope that helped!

Comment: I am having a bug where `C-c ~` messes up the table as you specified in step 2.
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/27.0.50/lisp/org/)

Comment: @ComproPrasad - How does the table get messed up?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DH65YgwH . Found out. If there is a missing newline at the end of file it breaks.

Comment: @ComproPrasad thanks. I wonder if this is a new bug. Still trying to figure out a work around besides reverting to earlier version of org-mode.

Comment: Have you tried manually moving `|----------+-------------------+` to next line down? Then updating `|` to `+` i.e. `|----------+-------------------+` with `+----------+-------------------+`?

Comment: Made a video: https://youtu.be/Jo4RlPqs0_c

Comment: @ComproPrasad - Awesome troubleshooting video with work around fix! I’ll update the example in my answer with your workaround! Thanks!

Comment: what is step 4? Is `t-r-t` shorthand for another command?  I've found that when dealing with tables that have text with embedded links, after step 3, only the column headings are selected, and I need a way to select each table cell, as in step 4. However, I don't know what step 4 is actually referring to, since `M-x t-r-t` shows nothing for me with org-mode 9.1.9

Comment: @adamc - I think the `t-r-t` is short for `table-recognize-table` which is part of `table.el`. When I substituted `M-x table-recognize-table` for `M-x t-r-t` in step 4, each cell of the table was highlighted, which is the result you want. Did this extra info help?

Comment: @Melioratus Thanks for the response, but `M-x table-recognize-table` doesn't work for me when I have a table with links in it - only the table header is highlighted, the rest of the cells are not.  Also, it might be worth editing your post and explicitly including `table-recognize-table`, since `t-r-t` will bring up different commands depending on which packages are loaded.

Comment: @adamc - Thanks for quick response! I didn’t know about the issue with links in table cell. That is awful! I use links in tables all the time but have never tried to wrap any. Ugh! I’ll look for workaround. Please reply back if you find or create a solution before me and I’ll link to your fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wish there were explanations on how to edit the table once having converted it to `table.el`. For instance, it appears creating a new line does not work, you have to use `M-x table-insert-row`.

Comment: @kotchwane - I understand your frustration. Other than `C-c '`, I'm not sure there are any default key bindings in org for `table.el`. I rarely use `table.el` because the format lacks many features compared to `org-table`. For example, AFAIK `table.el` tables can't be passed to src blocks. Is there a specific reason why you want use `table.el` besides column wrapping?

Comment: @Melioratus: Thanks for your answer! You make some good points. No, besides column wrapping, I have no use for `table.el`, and even for that, I find that it is lacking, because the tables and columns created are more or less fixed-size. So it doesn't solve my problem of tables getting unreadable when I diminish the size of the window containing the org buffer.

Answer (score 12):

**Adjust Column Width with Wrap Around**

Here is a solution adapted for org-mode 9.1.13, Spacemacs (0.200.13), emacs 26.1 for convenience.

Starting with the following content at a buffer in org-mode:

```
| Verse No | Verse             |
|        1 | Line1 Line1 Line1 |
|        2 | Line2 Line2 Line2 |
```

Note that you must leave a NEWLINE on top of the above table to avoid the bug of table.el.

1. Convert the table to table.el format by `C-c ~`.

```
+----------+-------------------+
| Verse No | Verse             |
+----------+-------------------+
|        1 | Line1 Line1 Line1 |
+----------+-------------------+
|        2 | Line2 Line2 Line2 |
+----------+-------------------+
```

2. Directly adjust the column width by `SPC u 10 SPC SPC table-narrow-cell`.

```
+----------+---------+
| Verse No | Verse   |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | Line1   |
|          |Line1    |
|          |Line1    |
+----------+---------+
|        2 | Line2   |
|          |Line2    |
|          |Line2    |
+----------+---------+
```

3. Convert the table back to org-table format by `C-c ~`.

Comment: My newer spacemacs setup no longer works with the above solution. But I found that conventing to table.el format, then I can manually adjust the line wrap. After manual editing, then I can convert it back, and get the desired wraps.

Comment: `SPC u 10` is not required.  `10` auto-prefaces it to `C-u 10-`  (Emacs 27.0.50, Spacemacs 9.0.)

Answer (score 8):

Once you follow along the accepted answer and fixed the size of a long column in an existing table, toggling table-fixed-width-mode by `M-x table-fixed-width-mode` seems to do the trick of automatically wrapping (future) long lines of text in a column in table edit mode. You enter table edit mode by keying `C-c '`

**Tested on: Emacs 25.2.2, Org-Mode 9.1.6**